# has_and_belongs_to_many and joining tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having problems with has_and_belongs_to_many relation. I have 2 models, Doctors and PatientMeeting.

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :patient_meetings
end
class PatientMeeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :doctors
end
```

The problem is to show the patient meetings for doctors marked in the top50 (I have a bool variable called top50). I need to create a query that lists the meetings of these
doctors in descending order and include today and tomorrow dates only. I tried this and variations but it didn't work:

```
Doctor.joins(:patient_meetings).where(:top50 => true).where('patient_meetings.meeting_date' => Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")..Date.tomorrow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).order('patient_meetings.meeting_date DESC').limit(50)
```

I am out of ideas about what to do here next. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `mysql`. Try this

```
 Doctor.joins(:patient_meetings).where("patient_meetings.meeting_date <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND patient_meetings.meeting_date >= CURDATE()").order("patient_meetings.meeting_date DESC").limit(50)
```

Comment: Seems that I am having another problem. I can'f fill meetings with data. If I try for exaple d = Doctor.find_by_id(1) and then do d.patient_meetings = PatientMeeting.new I get error: undefined method `each' for PatientMeeting. I need to fill PM with some data to connect Doctor and PM.

Comment: @user2645029: You're asking totally irrelevant question in your comment. I'll answer though, try `d.patient_meetings << PatientMeeting.new`. I have no idea what validations you have in PatientMeeting model.

Comment: I wasn't sure which was the problem of those 2. But yes, I should stick to the topic. Thanks much, it worked.

Comment: If a PatientMeeting has attributes, use a has_many through, not a has_and_belongs_to_many. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PatientMeeting.joins(:doctors).where(doctors: {top50: true})
```

Comment: This returns an empty array - I have to use ".joins" not ".join" because it returns undefined method for ".join". Also, Where do I put the date requirement?

Comment: Sorry, I just figured that you wrote joins, seems that when I pasted it in my code, I missed s. Anyway, the question remains..

Answer (score 0):

The meeting that a patient has with a doctor obviously has particular attributes of its own, such as the time at which it will take place, possibly the location, possibly whether it took place or not.

It seems to me that it should therefore be a has_many through association, not a has_and_belongs_to_many.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many